# Updating SQL Table via VBA cuts off decimals

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I need to update a set of values from an Excel Worksheet into a SQL Server Table.
This is the Excel Table:

[image: 1]

I wrote some code in VBA to do this, but I'm not very expert.
The update work just fine except for the part where it truncate decimals.

[image: 2]

As you can see the decimals get cuts off. The fields on SQL are declared as Decimal (19,5).
Sure there's something wrong in the VBA code. Here's my code.

```
On Error GoTo RigaErrore

Dim cn_ADO As Object
Dim cmd_ADO As Object

Dim SQLUser As String
Dim SQLPassword As String
Dim SQLServer As String
Dim DBName As String
Dim DBConn As String

Dim SQLQuery As String
Dim strWhere As String


Dim i As Integer
Dim jOffset As Integer
Dim iStartRow As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'iStep = 100
jOffset = 20
iStartRow = 3
i = iStartRow

SQLUser = "xxxx"
SQLPassword = "xxx"
SQLServer = "xxxxxxxx"
DBName = "xxxxx"

DBConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Pesist Security Info=True;User ID=" & SQLUser & ";Password=" & SQLPassword & ";Initial Catalog=" & DBName & ";" & _
        "Data Source=" & SQLServer & ";DataTypeCompatibility=80;"

Set cn_ADO = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn_ADO.Open DBConn

Set cmd_ADO = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

While Cells(i, jOffset).Value <> ""
    xlsIDKey = Cells(i, 0 + jOffset)
    xlsVendSim = CDbl(Cells(i, 1 + jOffset))
    xlsOreSim = CDbl(Cells(i, 2 + jOffset))
    xlsProdVar = CDbl(Cells(i, 3 + jOffset))
    xlsOreSimVar = CDbl(Cells(i, 4 + jOffset))
    
    strWhere = "ID_KEY = '" & xlsIDKey & "'"
    
    SQLQuery = "UPDATE DatiSimulati " & _
                "SET " & _
                "VEND_SIM = Cast(('" & xlsVendSim & "') as decimal (19,5)), " & _
                "ORE_SIM = Cast(('" & xlsOreSim & "') as decimal (19,5)), " & _
                "PROD_VAR = Cast(('" & xlsProdVar & "') as decimal (19,5)), " & _
                "ORE_SIM_VAR = Cast(('" & xlsOreSimVar & "') as decimal (19,5)) " & _
                "WHERE " & strWhere
    
    cmd_ADO.CommandText = SQLQuery
    cmd_ADO.ActiveConnection = cn_ADO
    cmd_ADO.Execute
    
    i = i + 1
Wend

Set cmd_ADO = Nothing
Set cn_ADO = Nothing

Exit Sub

RigaErrore:
MsgBox Err.Number & vbNewLine & Err.Description
Application.StatusBar = False
Application.Cursor = xlDefault

If Not cn_ADO Is Nothing Then
    Set cn_ADO = Nothing
End If
If Not cmd_ADO Is Nothing Then
    Set cmd_ADO = Nothing
End If
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thanks everybody who could help solve this.

Comment: could it be a simple excel formatting issue? try to manually change the number of decimals in the format to see if you can see the full value.

Comment: I will (1) check the format in your excel (2) if ```CDbl``` is converting your cell value to a double despite your local configuration (```,``` instead of ```.``` ) which It should (3) Make sure that ```xlsVendSim``` ```xlsOreSim``` etc despite being ```Variant``` type are not truncating the value (you could declare them as ```Double``` to make sure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work-around would be to replace the decimal commas with dots.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub connectDB()

    Const SQLUser = "#"
    Const SQLPassword = "#"
    Const SQLServer = "#"
    Const DBName = "#"
    Dim DBConn As String

    DBConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Pesist Security Info=True" & _
             ";User ID=" & SQLUser & ";Password=" & SQLPassword & _
             ";Initial Catalog=" & DBName & _
             ";Data Source=" & SQLServer & _
             ";DataTypeCompatibility=80;"

    Dim cn_ADO As Object, cmd_ADO As Object
    Set cn_ADO = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    
    cn_ADO.Open DBConn
    Set cmd_ADO = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd_ADO.ActiveConnection = cn_ADO
  
    Const joffset = 20
    Const iStartRow = 3
    
    Dim SQLQuery As String, sIDKey As String
    Dim sVendSim As String, sOreSim As String
    Dim sProdVar As String, sOreSimVar As String
    Dim i As Long
   
    i = iStartRow
    
    ' create log file
    Dim LOGFILE As String
    LOGFILE = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\logfile.txt"
    Dim fs As Object, ts As Object
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fs.CreateTextFile(LOGFILE, True)

    While Len(Cells(i, joffset).Value) > 0
    
        sIDKey = Cells(i, 0 + joffset)
        sVendSim = Replace(Cells(i, 1 + joffset), ",", ".")
        sOreSim = Replace(Cells(i, 2 + joffset), ",", ".")
        sProdVar = Replace(Cells(i, 3 + joffset), ",", ".")
        sOreSimVar = Replace(Cells(i, 4 + joffset), ",", ".")
                
        SQLQuery = "UPDATE DatiSimulati " & _
                   "SET " & _
                   "VEND_SIM = " & sVendSim & ", " & _
                   "ORE_SIM = " & sOreSim & ", " & _
                   "PROD_VAR = " & sProdVar & ", " & _
                   "ORE_SIM_VAR = " & sOreSimVar & " " & _
                   "WHERE ID_KEY = " & sIDKey
                   
        ts.writeline SQLQuery & vbCr
        
        cmd_ADO.CommandText = SQLQuery
        cmd_ADO.Execute
        
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    ts.Close
  
    MsgBox i - iStartRow & " records updated see " & LOGFILE, vbInformation

End Sub
```